# HOST name is being changed when logging into the application

Tags: apache, ssl, grails, spring-security

I have a grails application that is using spring security plugin. The application is hosted in Tomcat with a facing HTTPD. I am forcing HTTPS using the following settings:

**server.xml in Tomcat**

```
<Valve
   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
   internalProxies=".*"
   protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"
   httpsServerPort="443"
   />
```

**httpd.conf** (To force HTTPS)

```
<Location /myapp>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://my.server.com/myapp [R,L]
</Location>
```

**ssl.conf**

```
<Location /myapp>
ProxyPass http://localhost:9090/myapp
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9090/myapp
        RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Proto
        RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</Location>
```

**Spring security settings**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [ '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL' ]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
```

**Problem**

I am able to access the site by `http://my.server.com/myapp` (get redirected to HTTPS). However, problem is when I try to login -- Upon submitting the username/password and clicking submit, I am being redirected to: `https://localhost/myapp/login/authfail?login_error=1` (Notice the host name has changed from `my.server.com` to `localhost`) . This happens on successful or unsuccessful logins.

Same problem happens on `logout` as well. Clicking on `https://my.server.com/myapp/logout` goes to `https://localhost/myapp/logout`

Below is the screenshot of tracking the network calls

[image]

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572667/grails-spring-security-redirect-to-login-page-using-https

Comment: I did come across that during my search. If you notice, I have exact same grails settings as mentioned in that answer (other than upper case `X-forwarded-proto` but that shouldn't matter). Making these changes did not help me

Comment: Have you set correct value in  grails.serverURL ?